# How to put data into a vector from a structure in another class that is in a binary file

Tags: c++, oop, vector

```
class Work{
public:

    struct dane {
        int id;
        char typeOfWork[5];
        char Title[50];
        char Author_lastName[40];
        char Author_name[50];
        int year;
        char Promotor_lastName[30];
        char Promotor_name[40];
        char keyWords[50];
        char summary[1000];
    };

    dane dane1;
};
```

In another class, I enter all values to this variables and save it to a binary file.

I want to save all this input into a vector in another class called `liblary`:

```
class liblary : Work{
    vector<Work> vec; // here is problem i want to keep all this inputs in this vector
    int how_many_works;
    void get_data(){
        //
        // Up here i have inputs for all this variables but I didn't copy it 
        //
        ofstream plik;
        
        plik.open("dane.dat",ios::out | ios::binary | ios::app);
        if(plik.is_open()){
            plik.write((const char *) &dane1, sizeof(dane));
            vec.push_back(dane); // Something like that to store all works in this vector but this ofc don;t work
            plik.close();
        }
    };
```

Ofc, in method `get_data()`, I didn't copy here all inputs of data, I did it just to show that that is in the `liblary` class and includes a binary file. This is a liblary system for a student thesis. I want this in `vector` because later I must add modify and searching methods in this OOP program.

Main question: How I can put all inputs what are getting saved to binary file, to vector.

Comment: Hi, hustlaxx.  Please read [ask] and give us a reproducible example detailing what you have tried, what you expected to observe, and what you actually observed.   Your question is open-ended, opinion-based, and impossible to answer here.

Comment: I don't really understand what the actual question is. Please clarify. Also, why does `liblary` (shouldn't it be `library` instead?) derive from `Work` and also have a vector of `Work`s? In any case, `dane1` is not an instance of `Work`, so it can't be stored in a `vector<Work>`, it would require a `vector<Work::dane>` instead.

Comment: Please help me out.  Convert all your character arrays to `std::string`.  You'll be glad you did.

Comment: @RemyLebeau first half or question  got an answer - a socio-professional deformation typical for novice programmers. I don't have a name for it and call it myself "OOP intoxication". They start to inherit any functionally related classes from each other.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews This may not be a good idea in this case. For saving into a file a fixed size data structure can be beneficial.

Comment: @hustlaxx You did indeed fix the formatting, thanks very much.

Comment: @PaulSanders nope, actually Remy did it :D

Comment: @Federico Oh, OK.  Personally, I wouldn't have.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, your code is a little odd, but it's not too bad. I'm going to ignore the oddness because you might actually have a reason for it.

Your vector is `std::vector<Work>`, but you're doing a `push_back` of a `dane`. You either need to change to a `vector<Work::dane>` or do `vec.push_back(*this)` instead.

I would make one other change. I don't know why you have a nested structure, but that's fine. I think it's dangerous to have `dane dane` the way you do, and I think it's doubly-dangerous you're leaving the contents willy-nilly.

I'd do this:

```cpp
std::vector<dane> vec;
if(plik.is_open()){
    dane myDane;   // This is new, and then I use it instead of dane1
    // populate myDane as needed...
    plik.write((const char *) &myDane, sizeof(myDane));
    vec.push_back(myDane); // Something like that to store all works in this vector but this ofc don;t work
    plik.close();
}
```

That is, I'd use a local copy of your `dane` so you're not mucking with the one inside your object -- unless there's a good reason you want it to be mucked with while loading your vector.

Answer (score 0):

Since you append the data I assume you want to load the data stored in a previous run. In this case open the file for both reading and writing, and read the elements from the file first and simply store any additional data written in the vector:

Simplified example only setting the summary of a single element, appending it and printing all summaries:

```
struct dane {
    int id;
    char typeOfWork[5];
    char Title[50];
    char Author_lastName[40];
    char Author_name[50];
    int year;
    char Promotor_lastName[30];
    char Promotor_name[40];
    char keyWords[50];
    char summary[1000];
};

class Library
{
    std::vector<dane> m_contents;
    std::fstream m_file;
public:
    Library(std::filesystem::path const& fileName)
    {
        // open file with
        // - input pos at the end (we want to know the number of elements) -> ate
        // - output pos at the end (we want to append data) -> app
        // - for reading and writing -> (in | out)
        // - no special treatment of line breaks -> binary
        m_file.open(fileName, std::ios::out | std::ios::in | std::ios::binary | std::ios::app | std::ios::ate);
        if (!m_file.is_open())
        {
            throw std::runtime_error("could not open file " + fileName.string());
        }
        
        auto existingDataSize = m_file.tellg();
        if ((existingDataSize % sizeof(dane)) != 0)
        {
            throw std::runtime_error("corrupted data in file " + fileName.string());
        }
        m_contents.resize(existingDataSize / sizeof(dane));
        m_file.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
        m_file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(m_contents.data()), existingDataSize);
    }

    void WriteElement(dane const& element)
    {
        m_file.write(reinterpret_cast<char const*>(&element), sizeof(element));
        m_contents.emplace_back(element);
    }

    void Print() const
    {
        for (auto& d : m_contents)
        {
            std::cout << d.summary << '\n';
        }
    }
};

int main()
{
    Library lib("lib.dat");

    dane d;
    std::cin >> d.summary;
    lib.WriteElement(d);
    lib.Print();
}
```